# XSLT SELECT FOR-EACH element in list

Tags: list, xslt, intersection

I'm currently using Biztalk for mapping.  I have a source order document that contains all parts that are being ordered.  The destination document needs to contain only rows that contain a valid item (CELL/@C004) in Valid/Sku list.  The valid SKU list is cached on the webserver and gets refreshed as necessary.  Rather than hardcoding the list of valid parts in the map, I'm using a c# script to call the webservice and the valid sku data is mapped into a xslt variable. Is this a good approach?

The best solution I'm thinking of right now is iterating over all of the Row data <xslt:for-each select"/SOURCE/ROWS/ROW"> and then doing a check to see if the item is in the list of valid items. Is there a more efficent way to do this?  something equivelant to select ROW/CELL[@Name='C004'] IN valid/sku list?

Source Document

```
<SOURCE>
...other nodes
<ROWS>
  <ROW type="D" index="0 ">
    <CELL name="C001" visible="X">
    <VALUE>80710693</VALUE>
    </CELL>
    <CELL name="C002" visible="X">
    <VALUE>10</VALUE>
    </CELL>
    <CELL name="C003" visible="X">
    <VALUE>100100</VALUE>
    </CELL>
    <CELL name="C004" visible="X">
    <VALUE>04001-17</VALUE>
    </CELL>
    <CELL name="C005" visible="X">
    <VALUE decimals="3">100.000</VALUE>
    </CELL>
  </ROW>
  <ROW type="D" index="0 ">
    <CELL name="C001" visible="X">
    <VALUE>80710693</VALUE>
    </CELL>
    <CELL name="C002" visible="X">
    <VALUE>10</VALUE>
    </CELL>
    <CELL name="C003" visible="X">
    <VALUE>100100</VALUE>
    </CELL>
    <CELL name="C004" visible="X">
    <VALUE>05001-17</VALUE>
    </CELL>
   <CELL name="C005" visible="X">
   <VALUE decimals="3">100.000</VALUE>
   </CELL>
 </ROW>
</ROWS>
</SOURCE>
```

list of valid values (about 1,500 values) from a webservice call.

```
<Valid>
  <Sku>04001-17</<Sku>
  <Sku>04002-17</<Sku>
  <Sku>04003-17</<Sku>
</Valid>
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath would be `/SOURCE/ROWS/ROW[CELL[@name = 'C004']/VALUE = $skus/Valid/Sku]` or with XSLT 2 or 3 I would define a key `<xsl:key name="sku" match="Valid/Sku" use="."/>` and use the path `/SOURCE/ROWS/ROW[key('sku', CELL[@name = 'C004']/VALUE, $sku)]`.